# How long does it take for super-strong monsters to respawn?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

How long does it take for super-strong monsters to respawn in *Dragon Quest Builders 2*?

Comment: Is "super strong monsters" a defined game term?

Comment: @Pyritie I don't know if it appear in game, but there is some web site, like [this one](http://www.gamersheroes.com/game-guides/dragon-quest-builders-2-super-strong-monsters-guide/), which use this term.

Comment: @Pyritie Yes, it is used in game on an alert when you approach them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be tied to ingame days: how many is unknown. It could even maybe a small chance every morning to spawn.

But if you were to get more Scaly Meat or get more statues from the super-strong monsters, sleeping over and over again should help spawning them instead of just waiting hours.